# extend a function defined on the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume f is a non-vanishing continuous function on the closed unit disc which is holomorphic on the open unit disc and has the property, that $ |f(z)|=1$ whenever $|z|=1$.

I define $ g(z)=f(z) $ on the unit disc and $g(z)=\frac{1}{{f(\frac{1}{z^*})}^*}$ outside. Since f is non-vanishing g is well defined and from the property of f on the unit circle one conclude that g is continuous. How can I conclude that g is also holomorphic outside the unit disc? I tried to use the power series expansion of f around 0, but I couldn't succeed. Can someone give me a hint maybe?

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to show that the function $h(z) =\overline{f\left(\frac{1}{\overline{z}}\right)}$ is holomorphic. To see this let $f(z) =\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_j z^j ,$ then $h(z) =\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \overline{a_j} \frac{1}{z^j}$ so it is analytic as a limit of sequence of holomorphic functions.

Comment: Okay this is enough because h(z) is not vanishing. Can I say, if the series is absolutely convergent that $\overline{\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \overline{a_j} z^j } = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_n {\overline{z}}^j $ ???

Comment: Yes, you can say that.